# Word cloud for Wordle to Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm making a little four panel brochure in Word. I've made a Wordle graphic and saved it to their cloud, but I don't know how to grab it and drop it in my Word doc as a picture. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQ](http://www.wordle.net/faq#pdf) on their site they list several options including PDF & SVG.

They basically suggest that you install [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/), or the equivalent, and 'Print' the graphic to a PDF.

Comment: Could you please provide a link and summarize the steps involved?